# How to register with 10DLC if I have another platform requesting me the same as twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

1. Do we absolutely have to register with The Campaign Registry (TCR)?
2. what happens if we don’t
3. Confirm that when I fill out the paperwork through Crelate (my other platform) and have to start paying $10 a month to the registry this will also meet the Twilio requirement (we shouldn’t have to pay 2x’s)

PLEASE YOUR ASSISTANCE WILL BE REALLY APPRECIATED.

Not applicable to this question at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, we highly recommend that you be fully registered and verified by July 5, 2023!
2. Messages sent that aren't registered and verified will be subject to a gradual increase in message blocking beginning on July 5, 2023. You'll also see an increase in error messages if you have not registered by this date. On August 31, all traffic will need to be registered!
3. What type of business are you? Direct brand, ISV? Please check out this guide on [how to register to use A2P 10DLC messaging](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260801864489-How-do-I-register-to-use-A2P-10DLC-messaging-) and follow the steps depending on which suites your situation